# ReactJS - compare 3 objects based on length and fill the difference with empty field

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 3 objects, each has a different length

```
obj1 = [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}] // length = 4
obj2 = [{...}, {...}] // length = 2
obj3 = [{...}, {...}, {...}] // length = 3
```

Based on the maximum length (here is 4), I need all of them to have the same length, like:

```
obj1 = [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}] // length = 4
obj2 = [{...}, {...}, {}, {}] // length = 4
obj3 = [{...}, {...}, {...}, {}] // length = 4
```

the difference should be empty because I need to know the valid elements later.

how can I have 3 object with the same length?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
// Define max length
const maxLen = Math.max(obj1.length, obj2.length, obj3.length);

// Push missing itens for each arr object
obj1.push(...new Array(maxLen-obj1.length));
```

If you have the possibility to add all your elements to an array, the operations became even simpler:

```
const arr = ... // your array of arrays
const maxLen = Math.max( ... arr.map(i => i.length));

arr.forEach( a => a.push(...new Array(maxLen-a.length));)
```